# Why does the OPA need a whole ship to destroy an asteroid?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

The Expanse S2e3 Static.

Spoilers for episode:

> Miller proposes using the Mormons' ship to destroy Eros to stop the protomolecule. Eros is about 10 miles in diameter as opposed to Deimos which is only about 6. Deimos was only destroyed by a few U.N. missiles. Wouldn't it just take a few more missiles to kill Eros or does the Belt not have that kind of weaponry?

Comment: Why is the Office of Price Administration destroying asteroids?

Comment: Office of Price Administration @user14111 good one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't gotten that far in the show, but in the novel *Leviathan Wakes*, it's explained that

> They can't just blow up Eros because that would scatter the protomolecule throughout space, making it impossible to prevent Earth, Mars, or, well, *anyone* from getting their hands on it. They need the *Nauvoo* not to destroy Eros on impact, but to use its incredible thrust *push Eros into the sun*, which they are confident will actually destroy the protomolecule.

Here's the transcript from my hard copy of the book, apologies for any typos:

> "Even if we studded the whole thing with nukes, how would we be sure that no little scrap of the thing would make its way to a colony or down a well? Blowing that thing up would be like blowing dandelion fluff into the breeze."
>
> Miller has never seen a dandelion, but he saw the problem. Even the smallest portion of the goo filling Eros might be enough to start the whole evil experiment over again. And the goo thrived on radiation; simply cooking the station might hurry the thing along its occult path rather than end it. To be sure that the protomolecule on Eros never spread, they'd need to break everything on the station down to its constituent atoms...
>
> "Oh," Miller said.
>
> "Oh?"
>
> "Yeah. You're not going to like this."
>
> "Try me."
>
> "Okay. You asked. You need to drive Eros into the sun."
>
> "Into the sun," Fred said. "Do you have any idea how much mass we're talking about here?"
>
> Miller nodded to the wide, clear expanse of the window, to the construction yards beyond it. To the *Nauvoo*.
>
> "Big engines on that thing," Miller said. "Get some fast ships out to the station, make sure no one can get in before you get there. Run the *Nauvoo* into Eros station. Knock it sunward."
>
> ...
>
> "The Mormons are going to be pissed."